# SQL Server: Checking the datatype of a column

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

How to check if a column in a table has a specific datatype?

For example, how to check if a column in *SQL Server* table is of datatype `char(11)`?

Answer (score 20):

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where DATA_TYPE = 'char'
and CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 11
and TABLE_NAME = 'your_table'
```

using `syscolumns`:

```
SELECT name FROM SYSCOLUMNS
where length = 11
and xtype = 175 --char type
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How should the query be, if I wan to use     SELECT * FROM SYSCOLUMNS.....

Answer (score 3):

```
select case when DATA_TYPE= 'char' then 'T' else 'F' end,    
case when CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 11 then 'T' else 'F' end    
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS     
where COLUMN_NAME = 'MY_COLUMN_NAME'     
and TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql Query for Checking the Data Type of Column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name data_type;
```